# contact solution on shabbat

Tags: halacha, shabbat, medicine, see-sight-vision-blind, cleaning

I use a contact solution that is hydrogen peroxide based. That is, the solution is hydrogen peroxide. The solution is put into a special case with a platinum disc at the bottom. The disc acts a catalyst for a chemical reaction. In the end I am left with clean contacts in what is effectively water. If wanted, you can read more about the product [here](http://www.clearcaresolution.com/faq.shtml).

Am I allowed to use this solution on Shabbos? Is there a melacha involved? What might a chemical reaction be likened to?

Comment: What type of lenses are they

Comment: What do you mean? They are the reusable kind (30 days). Are you looking for something more specific?

Comment: This looks very much like a CYLOR question. There are several melachot that _could_ be involved. As soon as you have a chemical reaction you are creating and destroying and heating/cooling, even if only at the theoretical level.

Comment: There is a halachic diff if they are soft or hard,since you have the 30 it must be soft

Comment: https://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/900100/rabbi-aryeh-lebowitz/ten-minute-halacha-cleaning-contact-lenses-on-shabbos/

Answer (score 5):

The page you link to indicates that the solution disinfects the lenses. Per [Torah.org](http://www.torah.org/advanced/weekly-halacha/5761/chayeisara.html) a disinfecting solution may not be used on Shabbos.

> On Shabbos, the lenses may be soaked in saline solution [so that the
>   lenses do not harden] but not in disinfecting solution.

See also [Rabbi Kaganoff](http://rabbikaganoff.com/can-contact-lenses-be-laundered-how-do-i-care-for-my-soft-contacts-on-shabbos/).

Comment: An issue of laundering, very interesting!

Comment: Know you  why. what is the fundamental difference between cleaning and washing. To clean vessels with bleach is prohibited?

Answer (score 2):

Rabbi Neustadt's "The Daily Halachah Discussion", around page 242, has a long discussion on the matter, including a discussion he had with Rav Elyashiv, he concludes that [as long as you are **not** especially particular about soaking your lenses in a disinfecting solution every night] you **may** soak them on Shabbos.
This is my understanding of what he writes, please look it up for yourself there.
(Some details: He says the Avnei Nezer would say it's not cleaning because the naked eye can't discern the cleaning, and Rav Elyashiv seems to hold that if you are particular on always cleaning in then that is enough to forbid.)