# Depilatories- creams or "shaving powders" on Shabbos

Tags: halacha, shabbat, technology, hair

Is it permissible to use Depilatories (creams or "shaving powders" which chemically dissolve hair) on Shabbos? and if not- why?

Comment: Related (shaving in general, not Shabbos): http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/19015/5323, http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16453/5323

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Har Tz'vi* ([*Yore Dea* 144](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=22460&pgnum=159)) says it's forbidden (by Divine, not rabbinic, decree) as a part of the prohibition on removing hair on *Shabas*. (He notes that use of a chemical is one of the standard ways of removing hair, so this doesn't count as a case of *kil'achar yad* that would remove it from the Divine prohibition.) *Sh'miras Shabas K'hilchasah* 14:41 cites this as practical *halacha*.

Comment: Great and to the point!

Answer (score -1):

The answer to this is probably based in the method by which most of those creams work. They are an acid, and essentially burn the hairs off of your face. This is the same basis as many chemical cleaners work off of. That is discussed a bit [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/35350/contact-solution-on-shabbat). Would you use hydrogen peroxide to clean with on shabbat? (Other than for a medicinal purpose)

Comment: JennaKO not clear what your saying