# Is using hair remover on a beard prohibited according the Tzemach Tzedek?

Tags: halacha, chabad, beard

Does anyone know if the ban of the Tzemach Tzedek on using scissors to remove beards also applies to [depilatory cream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_depilatory)?

I know that after the Tzemach Tzedek, the other Rebbeims gave other reasons for this prohibition but I just want to know this may be in accordance with the simple halacha of the Tzemach Tzedek.

Thank you

Comment: This might be interesting: https://files.anash.org/uploads/2020/06/theBeard.pdf

Comment: Strongly related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/99303/27180

Comment: The Lubavitcher Rebbe in his Likkutei Sichos, volume 7, p. 325 writes that even trimming the beard, e.g. to make it look nice, is included in ruling of the Tzemach Tzedek.

Comment: I don't have access to the sefer to check it, but ive read the reason is lo yilbash, if this is true, then it seems obvious that at least removing the beard with cream is not permitted, but just my thoughts. I also found this paper which brings early sources for this concept if you are interested: https://koshershaver.info/pdf/HPZ%20How%20to%20Respond%20to%20those%20who%20Challenge%20the%20Tzemach%20Tzedek.pdf

Comment: The question remains if using a depilatory cream is considered "cutting". See especially this thread, were it is explained that this sort of cream was used long before our time - https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/99303/27180

Comment: the issue you seem to be referring to is lo silbash which is different from the issue of cutting. As such it would seem the method of removing the hair would not matter since the end result is the same.