# Using depilatory cream during mourning

Tags: halacha, contemporary-halacha, hair, shaving, yoreh-deah

Inspired by [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/99303/33665) I was curious if it is permissible to remove hair with depilatory cream when mourning.

The reason is that there is a biblical prohibition against shaving hair (Deuteronomy 14:1) to mourn, but since it is *Muttar* to use depilatory cream on areas you’d otherwise be forbidden from shaving, does the same principle apply here that the biblical prohibition doesn’t occur since you’re not using an actual razor?

Comment: *it is Muttar to use depilatory cream on areas you’d otherwise be forbidden from shaving*... I don't think that's universally agreed upon.

Comment: By the same token, since all agree you can trim a beard, can you trim your hair during mourning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not permitted. From the language of the Rambam ([MT Avel 5:2](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1181886/jewish/Avel-Chapter-5.htm)), one sees the prohibition is not just in the act but also in the result. As such a depilatory cream which gets him to the outcome of being shaved is just as forbidden as a permitted shaver.

> Just as he is forbidden to cut off his hair; so, too, he is forbidden
> to trim his beard and any other hair on his body. **This applies to
> cutting hair and having one's own hair cut.**

I checked this with a *posek halacha* but anyone looking for how the law applies to him should check with his LOR.