# What Rabbinic discussion has there been about the use of contact lenses?

Tags: shabbat, contemporary-halacha

A chavrusa is an optician. He tells me that soft contact lenses will be squeezed when put in and taken out of the eyes.

My question is what, if any, Rabbinic discussion has there been about the use of contact lenses especially on Shabbos. Which Rabbis have said or written what decisions?

I am not asking for a discussion of the principles of the such use.

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/35350/759

Comment: Are you looking for references to written texts or just links to the various online responsa that google spits out?

Comment: I've answered based on assuming the generality of the question in your title. However, in the body, you mention specifically about squeezing. Please clarify if you're seeking a list of sources specific to this *melacha* or are you seeking articles that discuss other problems of using lenses on Shabbat?

Comment: A lot of discussion about if they are a chatzitza... https://www.google.ca/search?q=contact+lenses+mikvah

Comment: "A chavrusa is an optician." You should have asked him your question. Apparently, he sees things that you don't :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Dinonline](http://dinonline.org/2012/06/19/contact-lenses-on-shabbos/) cites rulings and opinions by Rav Shlomo Auerbach and Nishmas Avraham.

See, also, this related [M.Y. question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/35350/5275) for additional references.

Comment: I updated the Rabbi Kaganoff link in the related M Y question.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok *Chazak Ve'amatz*. I forgot to mention fixing the "cob"web site :-)